# Set IE10 to IE9 mode for specific sites

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

I would like to force IE10 at the browser level (not from the server side) to go into IE9 mode.

I know that I can do this manually through the F12 developer tools in the desktop version of IE10. Is it possible to force a site to always be seen in IE9 mode in both the Metro and desktop versions of IE10?

Comment: Can you describe why you need to force a specific IE version (for given sites only) in client-side?

Comment: We have a site that is not yet fully IE10 compatible and are blocking IE10 users. In the meantime, we have to support IE9 behavior, but if we're on Win8, we'll have to set compatibility mode every time.

Comment: How are you "blocking" IE10 users? I mean you can just set preferred browser mode with meta tag to IE9 and the site should work just fine for IE10 as well.

Comment: We're not there yet. Pushing changes to a production system are not something you just do when you support thousands of users.

Comment: We're blocking users by detecting their browser and deciding whether to let them login or tell them that their browser is unsupported.

Comment: Why are you blocking IE10 users when you can force them to use IE9 rendering on the server-side? Just see my answer for a direct solution.

Comment: The only way to explicitly force it on the client side is to set something on the server. Otherwise the user will need to manually configure it on their end to pretend to be IE9, but you can't control that.

Answer (score 7):

You can add your site to the compatibility view lists. Choose from menu "Tools" -> "Compatibility View settings" and in the popup dialog input your site.

[image: Compatibility View settings dialog.]

I've done it on the Windows 7, but I think that this solution applies to Windo

Solution found here: http://www.mydigitallife.info/force-ie8-to-load-and-display-websites-in-ie7-compatibility-view-mode/.

Comment: The problem with this is that it does IE10 Compatibility Mode. You can't force it to IE9 Standards Mode. Jira doesn't work properly in IE10 Compatibility mode but it does work properly in IE9 Standards mode.

Answer (score 4):

The best I can think if is forcing the browser to open in a specific mode by using a command-line option. Sadly, anything like this cannot be found from [the "official" list of command-line options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for IE. Also [discussions on Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/ieitprocurrentver/thread/f5ecfc0d-01e3-4d36-8608-406a6ec42aa9) also seem to imply that - at least on IE9 - you cannot permanently set document mode to a legacy setting.

Also I gotta say it puzzles me why you need to figure this out on client-side in the first place. I mean if you want to force IE10 users to use IE9 rendering mode then you just need to add an `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag with IE version at 9:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

From [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SetMode):

> In certain cases, it might be necessary to restrict the display of a
>   webpage to a document mode supported by an earlier version of Internet
>   Explorer. You can do this by serving the page with an x-ua-compatible
>   header. For more info, see Specifying legacy document modes.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a short-term client-side solution. Changing the server at the moment right now is not an option.

Comment: I'm really sorry to tell you, but I suspect such a solution doesn't exist. In addition, I gotta say it is very puzzling that you are developing a website and cannot change the server-side code -- how on earth can you develop the site if you cannot change it?

Comment: Given how surprised you are regarding our inablity to change production servers, I'm guessing that you haven't done enterprise-level development. When you're working on an enterprise system, changing ANYTHING is complicated. We have a test server that we can change no problem. We have a QA/certification server that we can change only after going through the test servers. Only after going through testing on both levels can we change prod. BUT those changes must be approved functionality before you even begin. It's just how it goes. We can change it, but a client-side solution would be simplest.

Comment: What's the problem in using the meta tag in your test server? Also please note that this site is a "Q&A site for computer enthusiasts". If you prefer talking about development specific stuff you could consider asking this in let's say stackoverflow.com

Comment: We have to support production, not just test. I know that you want to do it a certain way, but if it were that easy, I would have done that and not asked the question in the first place. I did not ask on stackoverflow because I am not looking for a coding answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm unsure, however, if I can help you any further. AFAIK it is not possible to force the setting on the client-side in the way you would prefer -- but maybe someone more knowledgeable will correct me.

Comment: I gotta say even when using this on server side, this solution doesn't work. I don't know if it's my environment but it's not working with IE10 (as IE9)

Comment: Let me give you an example. A company I do work for has a number of partners/suppliers who all have their own systems my customer orders parts through. Some run through VPN's some go out over the internet. The BEST of them requires IE9 or older to run, the worst has custom software that requires 32bit XP to run. We do not control these servers and are forced to deal with inter-operating with them. A lot of these enterprise systems don't get updated until something breaks.