# Force IE9 mode on IE10 browser for some websites

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I just started working in new company. they made an update to 1 website that only working on IE10. but user still have different websites that is not working properly in IE10. I tried changing Browser mode to IE9 and websites work perfectly fine. but when closing and reopening IE it converts back to IE10. is there a way to keep specific websites on IE9 mode?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [X-UA-Compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx) meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE9">
```

**Example:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Use Internet Explorer 9 Standards mode -->
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
  <title>My webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

There might be some other tricks as well:
[IE9 Compatibility Tricks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/16/ie-s-compatibility-features-for-site-developers.aspx)

The `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag is a server-side tag. You would put it in the HTML source code, inside the "head" tag, just as I showed in my answer. Do this for all pages on the website that should be viewed in IE9 mode. If you are looking for a client-side way to do this, I don't think there is one--at least according to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/502398/set-ie10-to-ie9-mode-for-specific-sites?rq=1).

Comment: thanks, is this going to stay only for specific websites or it will change setting for all websites in IE?

Comment: This meta tag only applies to the specific pages you put it on. It will cause any IE10 browser to display the page as if it were an IE9 browser. You will have to insert the tag into each page of each website that needs to be shown in IE9 mode.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. Do you just want to change the behavior of YOUR browser (e.g. for development) or of all browsers that visit each website?

Comment: I have 3 users that using 2 websites that not supported(not working properly) on IE10, but they do have 1 website that only works in IE10, so for those 3 users I need to set 2 websites in IE9 mode

Comment: Ricovox, can you please send me a screenshot of where exactly do I need to add Meta Tag? never done this before. in whitch tab? thank you

Comment: Please look at the bottom of my answer. I have updated it to explain "where" the tag goes.